# effect of table hint on view and table used inside that view

Tags: sql-server

We can use table hints like NOLOCK, PAGLOCK
but my question is... If table hints not used in view definition 
but used in query with view like

`SELECT * FROM myview WITH(nolock)`

will this effect on table used inside that view

Answer (score 1):

Logically it should ... cause the view query is going to run against the table as view doesn't store any data by itself (Unless it's a Indexed/Materialized view).

Per [Docmentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms187373.aspx) `TABLE HINTS` gets propagated to actual table. Little excerpt from the document [`Remarks` Section]

> All lock hints are propagated to all the tables and views that are
>   accessed by the query plan, including tables and views referenced in a
>   view. Also, SQL Server performs the corresponding lock consistency
>   checks.

But it also says that `TABLE HINTS` won't apply for computed columns computed from some other table column expression.

> If a table contains computed columns that are computed by expressions
>   or functions accessing columns in other tables, the table hints are
>   not used on those tables and are not propagated. For example, a NOLOCK
>   table hint is specified on a table in the query. This table has
>   computed columns that are computed by a combination of expressions and
>   functions that access columns in another table. The tables referenced
>   by the expressions and functions do not use the NOLOCK table hint when
>   accessed.

**TEST:**

create a table named `employee` as below

```
create table employee(id int not null, name varchar(20));
```

Inserted around `1572866` rows. So it takes sme time to execute.

create a view as below (see view definition has no table hints in place)

```
create view testview
as
select * from employee;
```

Select from view with table hint

```
select * from testview with(paglock,holdlock)
```

while this is on run .. try doing an insert on `employee` table and see yourself how `insert` will keep waiting for the `select .. rom view` to complete.